# How to explicitly document that a method does not throw exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, xml-comments, code-documentation

Using XML comments in C#, I can document that a method may throw an exception:

```
<exception cref="FooException">Thrown if foo is invalid.</exception>
```

However, if a method has no `exception` tag in its XML documentation, this may mean one of two things:

1. The author thoroughly tested the method, has made sure it will never throw an exception, and wants to document this fact by not adding an `exception` tag.
2. The author didn't care about documenting exceptions, so this method may throw anything.

In my experience, the second is usually the case. The question is, then:

**How do I explicitly document that a method will never throw an exception?**

The best I've come up with so far is to simply mention it in the method's `summary`, like "This method does not throw exceptions". But I was wondering if there is a more formal way to express this, like `throw()` in C++ (even though that may be a bad example).

Comment: It's very hard to guarantee that a method cannot throw *any* exception - consider `OutOfMemoryException` and `ThreadAbortException`. I guess the best you can do is to mention that the method should not normally throw exceptions in the `<remarks>` section.

Answer (score 2):

Adding it in the summary is good for documentation and communication with other developers.

You said you want to have a more formal way, tough.
From what I know of C# (very little), `Exception` has two main child classes, `ApplicationException` and `SystemException`. You generally can't guarantee that a system exception won't be thrown. We may however guarantee that no `ApplicationException` is ever thrown.

### 1. With contracts

With [code contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/), you may use `EnsuresOnThrow` post-conditions:

```
    Contract.EnsuresOnThrow<ApplicationException>( false );
```

### 2. Without contracts

Wrap the body of your code in a global `try/catch`, and assert `False` in the catch block.

**In both cases**, a static analyzer should understand that the assertion or post-condition can never be true when an exception occurs: thus, the application fullfills its contracts if and only if no exception is ever thrown from your function.